# sort string list by another string list python

Tags: python

```py
5 downvotes for what? like seriously wtf?

I asked a clear question and got a clear answer from Barmer.
Now i cant ask another question and now im forced to create a new stack overflow account and dont suggest that i dont cause your system is shit so yes i 100% absolutely will create a new one. and another one, and another one.

Eat shit.
```

So i have 2 lists.

list1 is the list of which order im trying to recreate.

list2 is the unordered list.

How to arrange list2 in same order as list1?

## List1

```py
list1 = [
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/smg/type100/fire",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/smg/type100/foley",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/special/bouncing_betty",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/special/flame_thrower/foley",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/special/molotov",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/special/ptrs/fire",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/special/satchel_charge",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/tank/kingtiger/fire",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/tank/ringoffs",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/tank/sherman/fire",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/tank/tank_reload/foley",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/tank/tank_reload",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/tesla/bounce",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/tesla",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/uber",
            "loaded_sound,stream/music/mission/zombie",
            "loaded_sound,voiceovers/zombie/ann",
            "loaded_sound,voiceovers/zombie/monkey/explo_vox",
            "loaded_sound,voiceovers/zombie/monkey/groan",
            "loaded_sound,voiceovers/zombie/monkey",
            "loaded_sound,voiceovers/zombie/monkey/raise_vox",
            "loaded_sound,voiceovers/zombie/pa"
        ]
```

## List2:

```py
list2 = [
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/smg/type100/fire",
            "loaded_sound,voiceovers/zombie/pa",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/smg/type100/foley",
            "loaded_sound,voiceovers/zombie/monkey/raise_vox",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/special/bouncing_betty",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/special/flame_thrower/foley",
            "loaded_sound,voiceovers/zombie/monkey",
            "loaded_sound,voiceovers/zombie/monkey/groan",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/special/molotov",
            "loaded_sound,voiceovers/zombie/monkey/explo_vox",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/special/ptrs/fire",
            "loaded_sound,voiceovers/zombie/ann",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/special/satchel_charge",
            "loaded_sound,stream/music/mission/zombie",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/tank/kingtiger/fire",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/uber",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/tank/ringoffs",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/tesla",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/tank/sherman/fire",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/tesla/bounce",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/tank/tank_reload/foley",
            "loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/tank/tank_reload",
        ]
```

## What ive tried:

```py
_newList = []
# sort list2 in same order as list 1
for i in list1:
    _line_ = i
    for j in list2:
        if j == _line_:
            _newList.append(j)
```

But all this did was recreate list2 as it is. it didnt rearrange anything.

Comment: If `list1` and `list2` are the same, besides the order, why have both?  If both are needed, why not just make a copy of `list1`?

Comment: What's the reason for `_line_ = i`? Why not just `for _line_ in list1:`?

Comment: `list2 = list(list1)`

Comment: Cause i have 1 list from 1 file & another list from another file.
The 2nd list is the list i use to get sound path, name & alias from but i need the order of list1.

a list1 item looks like this:
loaded_sound,sfx/weapon/special/ptrs/foley/gr_ptrs_clip_in.wav

list2 item looks like this:
loaded_sound,sfx/levels/zombie/tele/beam.beam_fx_home_start.beam_fx
splitting this line by '.' == path, name and alias. but when grabbing this info from list2 and it has to come from list1 i then lost the order of list1.

so i want to create a new list by the path in list2 to be in same order as list1

Comment: *"But all this did was recreate list2 as it is. it didnt rearrange anything."* - That's just not true.

Comment: it looks almost identical to me. maybe i messed up somewhere perhaps. either way this issue is solved now.

Comment: @phil, your actual question is in one of your comments. You should rephrase your question.

Comment: but when grabbing this info from list2 and it has to come from list2 i then lost the order of list1***

made a boo boo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the index in `list1` as the key when sorting `list2`.

If the lists are long, it would be good to create a dictionary that returns the indexes, rather than searching for each.

```
list1_dict = {val: i for i, val in enumerate(list1)}
list2.sort(key = lambda x: list1_dict.get(x, -1))
```

If there are any elements in `list2` that aren't in `list1`, this will sort them to the beginning.

Comment: ah ty sir this has worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you the following one-line style code:

```
list2 = [i for i in list1 if i in list2]
```

Comment: this is returning the same mixed list as my code

Comment: @phil I do not agree. `new_list` contains the same elements as `list2` but arranged in same order as `list1`.

Comment: i used ur code and printed out both list1 and list2 and list2 didnt match list1 but did match my mixed list.

Comment: @phil So replace `new_list` by `list2` in my code if you want to update `list2`. I have updated my answer.